# org mode sum time from remote table with org-lookup-all

Tags: org-mode, org-table, calc

I have two tables

```
#+NAME: tasks
| name   | spent  |
|--------+--------|
| task 1 |        |
| task 2 |        |
| task 3 |        |
| task 4 |        |
| task 5 |        |
```

```
#+NAME: works
| date             | task   |     time |
|------------------+--------+----------|
| <2020-10-17 Sat> | task 1 |     0:05 |
| <2020-10-18 Sun> | task 1 |     0:10 |
| <2020-10-19 Mon> | task 2 |     1:00 |
| <2020-10-20 Tue> | task 3 |     1:25 |
| <2020-10-21 Wed> | task 4 |     0:10 |
| <2020-10-22 Thu> | task 4 |     2:30 |
```

How to calculate total time spent to task in table `tasks` column `spent` using `org-lookup-all`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works for me:

```
(org-table-time-seconds-to-string
 (apply '+
        (mapcar 'string-to-number
                (mapcar 'org-table-time-string-to-seconds
                        (org-lookup-all
                         $1
                         '(remote(works,@2$2..@>$2))
                         '(remote(works,@2$3..@>$3))))))
 'hh:mm)
```

`org-lookup-all` returns something like `("0:05" "0:10")`.

---

```
#+NAME: works
| date             | task   |     time |
|------------------+--------+----------|
| <2020-10-17 Sat> | task 1 |     0:05 |
| <2020-10-18 Sun> | task 1 |     0:10 |
| <2020-10-19 Mon> | task 2 |     1:00 |
| <2020-10-20 Tue> | task 3 |     1:25 |
| <2020-10-21 Wed> | task 4 |     0:10 |
| <2020-10-22 Thu> | task 4 |     2:30 |

#+NAME: tasks
| name   | spent |
|--------+-------|
| task 1 | 00:15 |
| task 2 | 01:00 |
| task 3 | 01:25 |
| task 4 | 02:40 |
| task 5 | 00:00 |
#+TBLFM: $2='(org-table-time-seconds-to-string (apply '+ (mapcar 'string-to-number (mapcar 'org-table-time-string-to-seconds (org-lookup-all $1 '(remote(works,@2$2..@>$2)) '(remote(works,@2$3..@>$3)))))) 'hh:mm)
```

I learnt how to use the function via https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-lookups.html, the webpage contains some examples.

Comment: Thank you some much. It works as expected. But how did you find out about functions `org-table-time-seconds-to-string` and `org-table-time-string-to-seconds`? I have tried to find something like these but nothing have found

Comment: @osadasami 1) Most Spreadsheet apps support the time&date datatype and provides functions to work with them, 2) then I search "time" in (info "(org) Top"), and notice it does support duration (info "(org) Durations and time values"), so org mode must provides utility functions for time/duration, and the info page mentions the variable org-table-duration-hour-zero-padding 3) C-h v on the variable then jump to the source file org-table.el, then search functions about time via M-x helm-imenu time, this is how I found these two functions.

Comment: A small nit: can you fix the final sentence of your answer? It's missing a verb but I don't know which one :-) Otherwise, thanks for the answer (and that link).

Comment: @NickD thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In Calc (the Emacs embedded calculator) there is a format for hours-minutes-seconds that you may leverage. For instance, 1 hour, 25 minutes, 17 seconds is written `1@ 25' 17"`. Here is a variation of xuchunyang's answer with this format:

The input table:

```
#+NAME: works
| date             | task   | time      |
|------------------+--------+-----------|
| <2020-10-17 Sat> | task 1 | 0@ 05' 0" |
| <2020-10-18 Sun> | task 1 | 0@ 10' 0" |
| <2020-10-19 Mon> | task 2 | 1@ 00' 0" |
| <2020-10-20 Tue> | task 3 | 1@ 25' 0" |
| <2020-10-21 Wed> | task 4 | 0@ 10' 0" |
| <2020-10-22 Thu> | task 4 | 2@ 30' 0" |
```

The sums:

```
#+NAME: tasks
| name   | spent     |
|--------+-----------|
| task 1 | 0@ 15' 0" |
| task 2 | 1@ 0' 0"  |
| task 3 | 1@ 25' 0" |
| task 4 | 2@ 40' 0" |
| task 5 | 0         |
#+TBLFM: $2='(math-format-value (calcFunc-vsum (cons 'vec (mapcar #'math-read-expr (org-lookup-all $1 '(remote(works,@2$2..@>$2)) '(remote(works,@2$3..@>$3)) )))))
```

Note that Org Mode tables understand this `@ ' "` format. Therefore you may use it in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, you may want to look at the `OrgAggregate` package available on `Melpa`. It does all kinds of aggregations. In your example with the `@ ' "` format, it will use the `task` column as a key, and sum up the `time` column values. You don't have to create the receiving table, `OrgAggregate` takes care of it.

```
#+BEGIN: aggregate :table "works" :cols "task vsum(time)"
| task   | vsum(time) |
|--------+------------|
| task 1 | 0@ 15' 0"  |
| task 2 | 1@  0' 0"  |
| task 3 | 1@ 25' 0"  |
| task 4 | 2@ 40' 0"  |
#+END:
```

Documentation here: https://github.com/tbanel/orgaggregate